# How to delete value from jsarray in GWT?

Tags: gwt

i have two questions:
1) is it possible to delete any value in jsarray or only the last on with the pop method?
2) how can i remove or delete a value from jsarray? does somebody can post an example.
something like this here

```
public JsArray<MyObject> myObjects = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
myObjects.push(new MyObject("Good"));
myObjects.push(new MyObject("morning"));
myObjects.push(new MyObject("people"));
myObjects.delete(1);
```

thx a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are *sparse*, so you cannot, for example, remove an object from it and have all the following be moved up to lower indices (like you'd have in Java with a `List` for instance); at least not with some *remove* method.

Using only GWT Java, you can set the value at a specific index to `null`, but that's it.

Using JSNI, you can delete it (almost equivalent to setting it to `undefined`: `delete myObjects[1]`) or you can remove it:

```
public static native remove(JsArray<?> arr, int index, int count) /*-{
   arr.splice(index, count);
}-*/;
```

Comment: Any idea why [it's not working here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229909/getting-uncaught-typeerror-arr-0-g-splice-is-not-a-function)? :/