# How can I remove element from JsArray<T>?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I need to remove element from `com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray`. Also I need to empty the JsArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here: [How to delete value from jsarray in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395353/how-to-delete-value-from-jsarray-in-gwt)

> Arrays in JavaScript are sparse, so you cannot, for example, remove an
>   object from it and have all the following be moved up to lower indices
>   (like you'd have in Java with a List for instance); at least not with
>   some remove method.
>
> Using only GWT Java, you can set the value at a specific index to
>   null, but that's it.
>
> Using JSNI, you can delete it (almost equivalent to setting it to
>   undefined: delete myObjects[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395353/how-to-delete-value-from-jsarray-in-gwt)) or you can remove it:  public static
>   native remove(JsArray arr, int index, int count) /*-{
>
>   arr.splice(index, count); }-*/;