# How to delete an item from a collection in the DOM, GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am newbie on GWT. I am writing the code of a page which asks a JSON object that contains two collections and I use one of these collection to fill a `Flextable`. 
This is my JSON Object:

```
public class Users extends JavaScriptObject {

 protected Users() {
 }

 public final native JsArray<Link> getLinks() /*-{
    return this.links;
 }-*/;

 public final native JsArray<User> getCollection() /*-{
    return this.collection;
 }-*/; 
}
```

In particular I am using the second collection (called `collection`) to fill a `Flextable`.
 But my problem is that when I delete one row from the table, even if I send a request with an http delete method to the server (and the server delete that item successfully), when I try to refresh the table GWT does not generate the GET request to the server, (even if it is written in the code) and Users Object is the same as before with the deleted item also.
I have tried to delete this item from collection using this method:

```
public static native void remove(JsArray<?> arr, int index, int count) /*-{ 
                                                                              arr.splice(index, count);
                                                                    }-*/;
....
remove(users.getCollection(), index, users.getCollection().length());
```

And I also tried this other technique:

```
 users.getCollection().set(index, null);
```

But in both cases, I do not get the expected result, when I refresh the table I find the deleted items again. 
I think that I am not managing the DOM properly,
 Do you have any suggestions? Any Idea? I am sure it is simple problem to solve for an expert.

**EDIT:** 
The user can refresh the data in the table clicking a button, the handler of this event will perform a request to a server, but this request is sent on the first click only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two alternatives, the first is to set the header `Cache Control` to `no-cache` in the server side, while if you cannot modify the code in the server side, for example in the case of legacy applications, you can attach a random number in your request in a parameter. A request will have a uri with an additional parameter which is a random generated number, `http:\\mydomain.com\something?random=12345`. Two different requests will have different numbers and at the second request the response of the first request, which has been cached it will be ignored. It is not a smart practice, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

For getting data like this better use HTTP POST request, because GET requests are being cached (by GWT, proxy servers...).

Also make sure your server code for deleting items is doing right job, and manually check server response in firebug or in chrome console to see if your response contains deleted records.

Please post code you use to fill flex table, are you clearing it before populating with data again ?

EDIT:

see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395353/how-to-delete-value-from-jsarray-in-gwt).

If you can use celltable http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable (because it holds List of elements it display underneath) or use some collection (ArrayList) to hold data that your FlexTable is displaying. Then you can easily modify that collection and redraw your flex table from it.

Comment: GET is not the problem. The problem is that if the data shouldn't be cached, then the response should say so. And it's OK to cache it but the client doesn't want to use its cached data, then it should say so in the request (setting the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header).

Comment: yes, you can set Cache-Control for GET, or just change request type for POST, I think that using POST is more elegant. Using GET for any kind of data fetching is ugly practice and can cause you lot of pain when you don't realize it's limitations (like URI Length, need to encode all parameters etc. etc.).

Comment: Yes, exactly Thomas. Previously, I have tried to set `Cache control: no-cache` and it worked. But, I am not sure that is a good practice, because we need to cache data, and in addition a lot of interactions with the server would be too expensive.

Comment: @JakubPawłowski Using POST for any kind of data fetchig is an ugly practice and can cause you a lot of pain when you don't realize it's limitations (nothing will ever be cached which prevents any further network optimization; also think about performance, particularly on mobile).

Comment: @daniele It depends how you want to handle things. Usually, using `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` (in addition to `max-age`, and possibly `public` or `private` to make things explicit) in the response is enough. Use `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the request only for cases when you explicitly want to bypass the cache (such as after modifying or deleting a value). Obviously, the lightest way is just to remove the row from your local data without fetching (at the expense of stale data); you could also have the `DELETE` return the list to save one request (not always possible though).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I am looking for a solution which will not affect the server side adding new headers: Is it possible to modify the cached object in the client side? If yes, How? Probably, the solution will consist in forcing the client to do the request, but I am wondering How can I force the request if the response from the server does not have the `Cache Control` header?